# how to calculate the degree of consistency between two methods?

Tags: statistics, similarity, spss

I have a sample of 22 learners and I used two different methods to identify their personalities. My problem is I am not that good in statistics and I want variables that I can use within SPSS to calculate the degree of consistency between these two methods (i.e the learner 1 has X as his personality in method 1 and X as his personality in method 2....).
Besides, can I use some graphs in SPSS to generate plots for each method.
This can help readers to easily see if there is a consistent results in the two methods or not. Thank you.

Comment: Are the two variables ordinal, nominal or scale?

Comment: Please give a short example of how your data is organized. Is it in long form (variables might be: lernerNr. Method, Personality, ...) or in wide form (variables might be: lernerNr, Personality-Method1, Personality-Method2, ...)?

Comment: relating to @figurine's comment, are you interested in a measurement of how often the results of method 1 and method 2 differ from each other, or do you also want to measure the distance between the two values of both methods (this requires scale or ordinal variables).

Comment: @mirirai My data is structured as follows:  learner:1, personality with method 1= extrovert, personality with method 2= introvert ....
Yes i'm interested in a measurement of how often the results of method 1 and method 2 differ from each other.
Thank you

Comment: Are personality with method 1 and personality with method 2 both dichotomous? (ie just introvert/extrovert) Or is there a further range of possible values?

Comment: the personality value can be: introvert, extrovert or moderate.
By the way, I used Kappa variable to measure the degree of agreement. what do u think? and is there any other way to validate my new method. Thank you.

Comment: Kappa would be fine for measuring agreement on two categorical variables. The easiest way to display agreement for readers would be a table with method 1, then broken down into intro, extro, mod for the rows and method 2, then broken down into intro, extro, mod for the columns. Should show the level of agreement and the kappa value will give the significance of this agreement.

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate how often results of method 1 and method 2 differ

In the following example I have 4*2 Variables (V1 to V4) with M1 (Method 1) and M2 (Method 2).

```
COMPUTE differences = (V1_M1 ~= V1_M2) 
                    + (V2_M1 ~= V2_M2) 
                    + (V3_M1 ~= V3_M2) 
                    + (V4_M1 ~= V4_M2).
```

**Explanation:**
The term `(V1_M1 ~= V1_M2)` returns 0 if both variables are equal and returns 1 if both variables have different values. In the end you sum all these terms up to get the number of total differences between those two methods.

## Calculate the sum of distances/ranges between the results of method 1 and method 2

```
 COMPUTE distances = ABS(V1_M1 - V1_M2) 
                   + ABS(V2_M1 - V2_M2) 
                   + ABS(V3_M1 - V3_M2) 
                   + ABS(V4_M1 - V4_M2).
```

**Explanation:**
The term `ABS(V1_M1 - V1_M2)` returns the absolute (positive) distance between the values of v1 with method 1 and method 2. All distances are summed up in the end.

If your variables are dichotomous this method will give the same result as the first method.

Comment: @figurine Thank you very much for all your time and guidance. I have another question if you dont mind: what do you think about Bland-Altman Plot to assess the level of agreement? will it be useful in my case?

Comment: There's a good explanation of Bland-Altman Plots [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-does-one-interpret-a-bland-altman-plot). Your questions might be better over at Cross Validated too.